# I'm trying to get a javascript function that will return a new array by using callback method and takes a array and two callbacks as arg

Tags: javascript, callback

I want to a function to accept two callbacks and return a result only if both callbacks are true:

```
let myMap = function(array, cb1, cb2) {
  let result = []
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    let test = cb1(array[i]) && cb2(array[i])
    result.push(test)
  }

  return result
}
```

The desired behavior:

```
let triple = function (n) {
    return 3 * n;
};

let half = function (n) {
    return n / 2;
};
console.log(myMap([7, 3, 2, 9, 8], triple, half));
// [ 21, 1.5, 6, 4.5, 24 ]
```

Comment: Your question describing what you want to happen ("return a result if only the two passed callback as arg are true") and the expected result (`[ 21, 1.5, 6, 4.5, 24 ]`) are two totally different things. Please fix the question and/or expected result so it makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

From the desired result, it appears that you're looking to *alternate* the calls of the callbacks for different array elements. You're not pushing/returning only if the callback is true, you're unconditionally pushing depending on the results of one of the callbacks, which is decided on by the index.

```js
let myMap = function(array, cb1, cb2) {
  let emptyArr = []
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    let test = (i % 2 === 0 ? cb1 : cb2)(array[i]);
    emptyArr.push(test);
  }
  return emptyArr
}

let triple = function(n) {
  return 3 * n;
};

let half = function(n) {
  return n / 2;
};
console.log(myMap([7, 3, 2, 9, 8], triple, half));
```

Or, cleaned up some

```js
const myMap = (array, cb1, cb2) => array.map(
  (val, i) => (i % 2 === 0 ? cb1 : cb2)(val)
);
const triple = n => 3 * n;
const half = n => n / 2;
console.log(myMap([7, 3, 2, 9, 8], triple, half));
```

Comment: Even more clever would be `[cb1, cb2][i % 2]`. And that could easily be expanded to support an arbitrary number of callbacks by using `...callbacks` as the parameter.